# How to fake a mouse event in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a bot who plays Tetris game.But in the source code(it has GUI interface) I have to press to play button and the new game starts.But since I want the bot to play it I have to surpass/skip the "play button". I am using pygame library in Python.How can I create such an event or circumvent the fact of pressing the play button ?

Comment: you don't need to fake a mouse event

Comment: I congratulate you on your sarcasm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mouse (or any other event) can be created in this way: Create a [`pygame.event.Event`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) instance and pass the event type (there's a list at the top of the linked page) and the relevant attributes as a dictionary or keyword arguments (in this case the `pos` and the `button`).

```
mouse_event = pg.event.Event(pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, {'pos': (245, 221), 'button': 1})
```

This event needs to be added to the event queue with the [`pygame.event.post`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.post) function so that it can be handled in the event loop. A minimal, complete example:

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue')
button = pg.Rect(200, 200, 90, 40)
# Create an Event instance and pass the event type
# and a dict with the necessary event attributes.
mouse_event = pg.event.Event(pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, {'pos': (245, 221), 'button': 1})

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if button.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print('collision')

    # I just add the event to the queue once per frame.
    pg.event.post(mouse_event)

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, button)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```